# How to get notified when MKMapKit zoom level changed?

Tags: mapkit

I need to update annotations in `MKMapView` when zoom level changed. I haven't found any appropriate method in `MKMapViewDelegate`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want:

```
mapView:regionWillChangeAnimated:
mapView:regionDidChangeAnimated:
```

If you want a true zoom level, check out this category method for the math:

https://github.com/mapbox/mbxmapkit/blob/ade77616e9c74dbeb46df0629fc22ca4f56cf4a5/MBXMapKit/MBXMapKit.m#L30-L39